# Jenkins 2 - Sonar 6.3 - JaCoCo report not found

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to incorporate the cobertura report to SonarQube 6.1. I have followed this documentation:

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Usage+of+JaCoCo+with+Java+Plugin

To sum up, I have configured my Jenkins pipeline to run the following Maven statement:

```
sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn clean verify org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -Dsonar.jacoco.reportPaths=${env.WORKSPACE}/target/jacoco.exec"
```

The build log shows that the JaCoCo report has been generated:

```
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.9/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.9-runtime.jar=destfile=/var/jenkins_home/workspace/MY_PROJECT/target/jacoco.exec
```

But when it tries to access it, it can't find it:

```
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCoSensor [java]
[INFO] JaCoCo report not found: '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/MY_PROJECT/target/jacoco.exec'
```

I have verified that the file is correctly being generated in /target/jacoco.exe running this statement on my laptop:

```
mvn org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true clean verify
```

Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! The problem was in the order of the operations. After reordering the jacoco.exec file is found and the coverage information transmited to sonar:

```
sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent verify org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -Dsonar.jacoco.reportPaths=${env.WORKSPACE}/target/jacoco.exec"
```

Comment: It's funny how many things can go wrong with setting up something so simple. I had similar problem to yours, started experimenting with order of goals after seeing your answer, got it completely different than you but it worksss!